# How to clear out all buffered transactions in BaseChannel.receive()?

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I am developing a tool that simulates both acquirer and issuer through JPOS. Acquirer connects to our Gateway (or switch) on a port, sends the transaction, and switch routes that to our issuer port, which my tool is also connected and responding to. The tool receives the transactions to process through JSON in a POST request, and then loops through each txn one at a time to send to the switch.

I have a scenario where I'd like to be able to clear anything that is in the BaseChannel.receive() method, without having to disconnect the TCP connection.

For example, there's occasionally circumstances where my issuer tool is receiving extra messages that it is not expecting. It appears that all of this is being buffered in the channel connection. I would like to be able clear out this buffer without having to close the TCP connection and start another. Is this possible? I want any data cleared out of the line so my tool only processes the transactions it expects to.

I have tried doing a loop and calling channel.receive(), but this will wait forever for a transaction to come across the line.

Comment: Please, share the code you are using, so we can better understand your problem, are you directly calling channel.receive()? or interacting with the channel through its in and out queues?

If it's the first ase, then you could call receive() until it does not respond in some timeout, but this would no be the best, in the second case you could call Space.inp on the queue until it returns nothing.

Comment: Hi, yes it is the first case, directly calling channel.receive(). I agree, I could call it till there's a timeout, but that would mean having to send the transaction twice to get it to work. I'll see if I can add some code to the original post, but after re-reading it, I'm not sure if it will add any more context. it really is just a method calling receive() and doing some checks for the mti / error handling

Comment: After thinking about this a little more, I may end up redesigning how my tool receives transactions. Perhaps I'll make a thread to handle all transactions (including anything stuck in that buffer), and then make another thread to handle any custom responses I need for the issuer. This may eliminate the problem I have in this post altogether

Comment: Or, you could send jPOS QServer (if you're a server), or ChannelAdaptor (if you are the client) that does exactly that, and communicate with other jPOS components through the Space.

Comment: I could look into that as well. I decided not to go with Q2 because I needed a way to dynamically make connections to ports specified by the user, and I didn't see a way to do that in Q2 without making predefined files in the deploy folder.